# Regression yields much smaller standard deviation and the mean is off, what could be wrong?

Tags: regression

I'm modeling a regression problem. An initial attempt yields the following:

```
labels.mean(): 0.00018132978443886167
labels.std(): 0.013450786078937208

predictions.mean(): 0.0005549060297198594
predictions.std(): 0.00430255476385355
```

As you can see, the mean is off, and the standard deviation is totally different. I wonder what does it indicate?

My guess: does it mean that my features are not discriminative enough, so that the model see examples w/ positive and negative labels alike, hence the small variance in the output?

I'm running the regression using `XGBRegressor`, with early-stopping. I have 1M training examples, 100K validation examples (for early-stopping), and another 100K for testing purpose (for which the mean and the standard deviation are shown above).

I also checked that the label distribution of the three sets are mostly basically the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in standard deviation is nothing suspicious.  It is only to be expected, if you have a weak correlation.

Suppose the regression is `y ~ x`, i.e., `y = ax + b`.  Suppose that `x` only explains a small fraction of the variability in `y`, i.e., `y` is scattered all over the place and the least regression line only weakly fits the data.  Suppose also that the line is nearly horizontal (i.e., `a` is small).  Then the standard deviation of the predicted `y`-values will be small (since the line is nearly horizontal) but the standard deviation of the actual `y`-values might be large.

But really, the way to figure out what is going on is to *visualize the data*.  You should always start by visualizing the data.  Plot a scatterplot, and superimpose the least squares fit line on top of it.  I bet you'll immediately have a better sense of what might be going on.

Comment: Marking this as an answer not because it directly answers my question (which I realize is hard to nail on the spot), but because your answer provides a good way for anyone who shares the question to approach the problem and to find out the answer by themselves. Appreciate it.